# strcmp finaliza la ejecucion

Tags: c, punteros

El problema que tengo es que durante la ejecución de la siguiente función el programa(IDE codeblocks) crashea indicando lo siguiente: status -1073741510 (0xc0000005).

```
bool existeNombreCol(COLUMNA* cabeza, char *nombre) {
    COLUMNA* cActual = cabeza;
    if(cActual == NULL || &cActual->nom == NULL){
        return false;
    }else{
        while(cActual != NULL && cActual->nom != NULL){
            if(strcmp(cActual->nom,nombre) == 0){
                return true;
            }else{
                cActual = cActual->next;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Adjunto la definición de la estructura de dato y como la creo:
Definición:

```
typedef struct col {
    char *nom;              //nombre de la columna
    TIPO t;                 //tipo de la columna
    float max, min, prom;   //máximo, mínimo y promedio
    int histograma[5];      //información para histograma
    ETIQUETA *lista;        //lista de etiquetas STR
    struct col *next;       //puntero a la siguiente columna
} COLUMNA;
```

Generación de una ED columna(Hay otros métodos que la modifican):

```
COLUMNA* crearCol(char* nombre) {
    COLUMNA* columna = (COLUMNA*)malloc(sizeof(COLUMNA));
    if (columna == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    columna->nom = (char*)malloc((strlen(nombre) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(columna->nom, nombre);

    columna->t = VOID;
    columna->lista = (ETIQUETA*)malloc(sizeof(ETIQUETA));
    columna->lista = NULL;
    columna->next = (COLUMNA*)malloc(sizeof(COLUMNA));
    columna->next = NULL;

    return columna;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está aqui:

```
while(cActual != NULL && &cActual->nom != NULL){
    if(strcmp(cActual->nom,nombre) == 0){//LA EJECUCION SE DETIENE
```

debería ser:

```
while(cActual != NULL && cActual->nom != NULL){
    if(strcmp(cActual->nom,nombre) == 0){//LA EJECUCION SE DETIENE
```

**Explicación**

El `while` debe ejecutarse mientras el puntero al nombre no sea NULL. Ese se chequea con `cActual->nom != NULL`. El error está en que comparas `&cActual->nom`, que vendría siendo la dirección donde está el puntero al nombre. Como la estructura existe y tiene reservado un espacio para ese puntero, `&cActual->nom` siempre será distinto de NULL.

**Demostración**

```
int main() {
    COLUMNA col;
    col.nom = "Juan";
    col.next = NULL;
    char* nom = "Juan";
    char* nom2 = "Jose";
    
    printf("Buscando %s: ", nom);
    printf(existeNombreCol(&col, nom) ? "Existe" : "No existe");    
    printf("\nBuscando %s: ", nom2);
    printf(existeNombreCol(&col, nom2) ? "Existe" : "No existe");
    return 0;
    }
```

produce

```
Buscando Juan: Existe
Buscando Jose: No existe
```

Comment: Si lo pongo asi entonces el crash se da en la propia linea del while, puse el & para evitar que diese el fallo en esa linea ):

Comment: @carlos. También es posible que cActual->nom apunte a cualquier parte.

Comment: "Candid Moe y como puedo solucionar eso?

Comment: @carlos Primero inserta un `printf` entre el`while` y el `if` para chequear el contenido de `cActual->nom` y hasta donde llega antes de caer.

Comment: He colocado el printf justo antes de la linea que hace que salte y no llega a imprimir nada, en su lugar hace que salte el mismo fallo

Comment: @carlos. Agregue un programa de demo a mi respuesta, con la lista mínima posible (un sólo elemento). Espero que te ayude a revisar el problema.

Comment: le comento, acabo de implementar su código y me funciona! ahora bien. Si sigo la ejecución debida del programa y genero la estructura col a partir de la función que he proporcionado arriba es cuando falla, por lo que supongo que el fallo esta en esa función aunque no detecto donde